# Roundcube - how to enable user registration?

Tags: email, roundcube

Can anyone tell me if there is any possibility to enable some feature that allows users to create new e-mail accounts ?

Answer (score 4):

No, there is not. Roundcube is a mail client, nothing more. You can't create new mail accounts with Thunderbird either.

Creating new accounts is the job of the backend you configured in your mailserver.

The backend can be system users, in a database (MySQL, PostgreSQL, ...), in a directory service (LDAP, ...) or a combination. Depending on how you configured your mailserver it should be trivial to write a registration script to create new users.

I would, however, advise against it if your server is accessible from the internet. You are just inviting people to use your server to send spam mails.